# JQuery Read Cookie and pass it to a PHP Variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a cookie and need to read it with JQuery or just javascript if JQuery alone is not possible.

Then I need to pass the value of that Cookie to a PHP variable

Can this be done?

UPDATE: I need everything to happen in the same page.

1. Javascript reads the already existing cookie.
2. $somePHPvariable = MyJavascriptCookieValue;

I need to use Javascript to read this cookie because I am using a wordpress cookie created in function.php and php cannot read the cookie when it's create but after the next reload of the page, which is no good to me.

Comment: Why do you need to read it in jQuery/JavaScript first? Are you going to manipulate the value? Why dont you just read the cookie in PHP and assign it to a variable?

Comment: This is implicit in Jasper's answer below, but one thing worth pointing out is that when a page loads the PHP will be executed before any client side Javascript. So you can't pass the result of any js code to PHP code *in the same page load*. You can reload the page with the js result in the querystring, or use ajax to pass the result to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can directly get the value of the cookie with `$_COOKIE['variable_name']`...

If you really want to get the value of the cookie in JavaScript then here is one of a few different plugins to help read/write cookies with jQuery: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You can then use AJAX to send the cookie information to your PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'path/to/server-side.php',
    data : { cookie : $.cookie('the_cookie_name') }
});
```

This will send the cookie as the GET variable `cookie`. You will be able to access it via PHP like this: `$_GET['cookie']`.

Comment: Check-out my answer now, I think I updated it just after you posted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can access cookies in JavaScript via `document.cookies`, look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for details.

But if you want to access the cookie data in php, you could read the cookie in php from the variable `$_COOKIE["coockiename"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Browser sends cookies to you server with the request each time. You dont need any javascript or jquery or ajax requests to get it. Just use `$_COOKIE` global array in PHP.

Comment: Please see UPDATE and you'll know which I cannot use php to read this cookie value